# Remove last characters from string

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I have a long string dates that I receive from an API call and they are returned as

`Event Name 2017-03-23T10:00.000+01:00`

How do I trim it so that I can remove the characters from all of the events that I get back and be left with only

`Event Name 2017-03-23 10:00`

Comment: Combine `substring(start, end)` and `lastIndexOf` methods.

Comment: Parse this into an `OffsetDateTime`, and then output it using your choice of formatter.

Comment: You could try `str.split("\\.")[0]`

Comment: @Pshemo could you provide an example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I trim it so that I can remove the characters from all of the
>   events that I get back and be left with only
>
> Event Name 2017-03-23 10:00

*Try this:*

```
String str = "Event Name 2017-03-23T10:00.000+01:00";
String newString = str.replace("T"," ");
System.out.println(newString.substring(0, newString.lastIndexOf(".")));
```

*result is* --> `Event Name 2017-03-23 10:00`

***side note*** -  as you can see working with `Strings` is a bit inefficient in terms of constructing a new object each time, you may consider looking into **[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)**. However, if you're doing no more operations then I've already done then that should be fine.

**EDIT**

*Alternative solution*

```
String str = "Event Name 2017-03-23T10:00.000+01:00";
System.out.println(str.split("\\.")[0]);
```

***Note*** -  this is similar to the solution above but leaves the "T" where it currently is. you can then go on further and do what you wish to do with it.

Comment: This removes the T between the date and time but also removes all instances of capital Ts throughout the string. The date at the end of the string remains unchanged

Comment: @smithcommajohn the example you've provided didn't state no more than one "T" hence that's what I based my solution on.  so you only want the T between the date and time to be removed ? nothing else?. Nevertherless i'll provide an alternative solution.

Comment: @smithcommajohn your example doesn't have any other T. Please update your question to show proper input. Explain what can change and what is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Event Name 2017-03-23T10:00.000+01:00");
sb.setLength(27);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: This solution would work but the string that is returned has multiple instances of these events and I need to display each of them, this would return only the first 26 characters.

Comment: I edited my answer to extend the length to 10:00 I miscount the string

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (str != null && str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'x') {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
     }
```

Change `x` with your last character.